# How do I export CSVs saved in AWS S3 to DynamoDB?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I saw that it's possible to import CSVs uploaded to s3 directly to dynamodb but I haven't figured out how to do it properly yet.

I'm guessing my issue is likely related to the naming of my partition key vs the actual headers in my csvs but I am unsure.

Is there a way to easily import CSVs to dynamodb from s3 programatically?

I have 20ish CSVs that I upload to S3 via Python script:

```
import boto3

a_key = '...'
s_key = '...'
region = 'us-west-2'

def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=a_key,
                          aws_secret_access_key=s_key, region_name=region)
    try:
        s3.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
        print("Upload to Cloud Successful")
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return False

def snaps(team_name):
    uploaded = upload_to_aws(f'CSVs/{team_name}_snaps.csv', 'teamcsvs', f'CSVs/{team_name}_snaps.csv')

def short(team_name, short_year):
    uploaded = upload_to_aws(f'CSVs/{team_name}{short_year}.csv', 'teamcsvs', f'CSVs/{team_name}{short_year}.csv')
```

I followed this [guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-dynamodb-can-now-import-amazon-s3-data-into-a-new-table/) and expected my CSVs to seamlessly become a dynamoDB table, but my imports keep failing.

I've gotten a few different errors from the logs but the latest is:

```
{
    "itemS3Pointer": {
        "bucket": "teamcsvs",
        "key": "CSVs/atl22.csv",
        "itemIndex": 0
    },
    "importArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:874782694093:table/atl_snaps/import/01669752143020-2b8be4f0",
    "errorMessages": [
        "One or more parameter values were invalid: Value for Item.Score is ambiguous"
    ]
}
```

```
2022-11-29T13:04:57.021-07:00

Copy
{
    "itemS3Pointer": {
        "bucket": "teamcsvs",
        "key": "CSVs/atl22.csv",
        "itemIndex": 0
    },
    "importArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:874782694093:table/atl_snaps/import/01669752143020-2b8be4f0",
    "errorMessages": [
        "One or more parameter values were invalid: Value for Item.Score is ambiguous"
    ]
}
{"itemS3Pointer":{"bucket":"teamcsvs","key":"CSVs/atl22.csv","itemIndex":0},"importArn":"arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:874782694093:table/atl_snaps/import/01669752143020-2b8be4f0","errorMessages":["One or more parameter values were invalid: Value for Item.Score is ambiguous"]}
```

```
2022-11-29T13:04:57.021-07:00

Copy
{
    "itemS3Pointer": {
        "bucket": "teamcsvs",
        "key": "CSVs/atl22.csv",
        "itemIndex": 0
    },
    "importArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:874782694093:table/atl_snaps/import/01669752143020-2b8be4f0",
    "errorMessages": [
        "One or more parameter values were invalid: Value for Item.Score is ambiguous"
    ]
}
{"itemS3Pointer":{"bucket":"teamcsvs","key":"CSVs/atl22.csv","itemIndex":0},"importArn":"arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:874782694093:table/atl_snaps/import/01669752143020-2b8be4f0","errorMessages":["One or more parameter values were invalid: Value for Item.Score is ambiguous"]}
```

```
2022-11-29T13:04:57.021-07:00

Copy
{
    "itemS3Pointer": {
        "bucket": "teamcsvs",
        "key": "CSVs/atl22.csv",
        "itemIndex": 0
    },
    "importArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:874782694093:table/atl_snaps/import/01669752143020-2b8be4f0",
    "errorMessages": [
        "One or more parameter values were invalid: Value for Item.Score is ambiguous"
    ]
}
{"itemS3Pointer":{"bucket":"teamcsvs","key":"CSVs/atl22.csv","itemIndex":0},"importArn":"arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:874782694093:table/atl_snaps/import/01669752143020-2b8be4f0","errorMessages":["One or more parameter values were invalid: Value for Item.Score is ambiguous"]}
```

Comment: So what’s inside the CSV the error message is complaining about?

Answer (score 0):

You have not gotten a few different errors, you get the same one each time. Item.Score is ambiguous.

Can you share a snippet of your CSV file, that will help us determine the issue.